# GET http://localhost:3000 404 (Not Found)

Tags: reactjs, npm, fetch, local

I have a problem while fetching a file from the local npm server. There is a new project that has a simple fetch with the correct location to file. I'm getting a response as `App.js:5 GET http://localhost:3000/returnJsonFiles/json_tire.json 404 (Not Found)`

Please help me to fix this issue.

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Main extends Component {
  componentDidMount = () => {
    fetch(`./returnJsonFiles/json_tire.json`, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      }
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Lorem
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Below is a Screenshot with code and directory

[Screenshot of code + package.json + directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dMjk.jpg)

Comment: Look at the code of the server and how are you building the URL. Also try using the URL directly in a browser.

Comment: Usually if you know for a fact the directory and file location are correct, can you manually navigate to that directory by manually typing in the  URL?  If that fails .. its more likely an external settings, like an IIS sever denying for a particular reason.  But usually you don't get a 404 unless the files not there, so your path is not the "real" path .. so do some tests to display the actual path and compare.

Comment: Ok. But if i try do that:
import Tires from './returnJsonFiles/json_tire.json';
console.log(Tires)
it showing the json file in the console. Thats why i thinking the location is correct.
Maybe Im wrong. Thats why Im looking for smarter pearson than me.

Comment: I olso tryied to use location like that: "http://localhost:3000/returnJsonFiles/json_tire.json" but the same problem appears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From screenshoot of your code, I assume that you are trying to **fetch** your **json_tire.json** file which resides in your **src/returnJsonFiles** folder. As far as I know, our app that is rendered on the *client side can only fetch files that reside in the public folder of our react app*.
Other than that, the files should be imported. And in your case, should be done as follows:

```js
import jsonTire from './returnJsonFiles/json_tire.json';
```

and if you insist to use **fetch** approach, put that file into  your app's public directory:

```js
app-root
  - node-modules
  - public
    - returnJsonFiles
      - json_tire.json   // <---- put here
  - src
```

Comment: I moved returnJsonFiles to public folder and it's working. Thanks Mate

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad to hear it.